# how do split a inputted word to letters then pull information from a dictionary from those letters

Tags: python

How would I return a value from a created dictionary based on inputed text?

```
Word = input ("input text:") 
splitted = split (word) 
thisdictionary = {"a": [tuple ([1,0]),tuple ([0,1])} 
y = thisdictionary.get (splitted) 
print(y)
```

Comment: None of this code works. What would a "dictionary based on inputed text" even look like? I can imagine a `list` like `splitted = list(Word)` but.. a dictionary?

Comment: you can make a string into a list simply by calling `list()` on it

Comment: Please refine the question and provide working code up to the point where the issue appears.

Answer (score 1):

To change string to a list of letters, just pass the string to list() method.

```
strSample="se"

strToList= list(strSample)
print(strToList)
```

I didn't quite get the second part of your question. But if you're asking that each letter is key to the dictionary then you can just loop over list of letters and pass them as dictionary[key].

```
d = {"s":"First letter", "e":"Second letter"}

for item in strToList:
    print(d[item])
```